# How come PIL + ndarrays are only working for black and white mode?

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing, numpy, python-imaging-library

Let me use a piece of code and a more succinct description instead.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image as im

real_img = im.open('test.jpg').convert('L') #comment the .convert('L') and it no longer works
old_img = np.array(real_img)
new_img = np.zeros(old_img.shape)
for i_row in xrange(old_img.shape[0]):
    for i_col in xrange(old_img.shape[1]):
        new_img[i_row][i_col] = old_img[i_row][i_col]
new_real_img = im.fromarray(new_img).convert('L') #comment the .convert('L') and it no longer works
new_real_img.save('test2.jpg')
```

This code just takes an image and tries to copy it (in my code I'm doing more than that, but this is enough for the example as this illustrates my problem). If you run it as is (with an image called 'test.jpg' at the same folder), it works. However, if you remove the `convert('L')` on the two lines it appears, it no longer works. I also can't convert it to `'RGB'` or some other useful format.

So the problem seems that I can't use ndarrays with PIL as long as I'm using color images. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Found [this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t709031-pil-problem-to-convert-an-image-array-to-pil-format.html).

"Image.fromarray() expects one bit per pixel but actually gets one byte."

So despite everything apparently being equal, it seems the convert methods are transforming the values onto their binary representations under the hood? I'm not sure tbh. But this fixes the problem:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image as im

real_img = im.open('test.jpg')
old_img = np.array(real_img)
new_img = np.zeros(old_img.shape)
for i_row in xrange(old_img.shape[0]):
    for i_col in xrange(old_img.shape[1]):
        new_img[i_row][i_col] = old_img[i_row][i_col]
new_real_img = im.fromarray(new_img.astype('uint8'))
new_real_img.save('test2.jpg')
```

So, convert the ndarray to `'uint8'` when going back to the image and it should be fine.